# Sects that offer proofs of which deities are NOT Brahman

Tags: sri-vaishnava, brahman, sects

Most sects cite scripture that says that their deity is Brahman. As far as I know, they do not offer elaborate refutations of scriptural claims regarding other deities.

But Srivaishnavites not only claim to prove that their deity is Brahman, they also claim to prove that no other deity is Brahman.  Some of the techniques they use are highly sophisticated - like purva-mimama,samanadhikaranam,chaga-pashu nyaya, rules of Paninean grammar - to name a few.

Are there any other sects that claim to do this?

Note: not asking for the merits or otherwise of Srivaishnavite claims. Just asking if any other sect makes claims regarding who is not Brahman.

Comment: Brahman is एकमेवाद्वितीय , so by restricting Brahman to a specific deity only, one automatically makes it clear that they view other deities to be mere जीवात्मन् .

Comment: Gaudiyas seem to regard Siva as "almost God"  "When milk is transformed by acids into yogurt, the yogurt is neither the same as nor different from the milk. I adore the primeval Lord Govinda, of whom Lord Shiva is a transformation for performing the work of destruction. (Brahma Samhita 5.45)"